# Angular Material: Cross-browser search input with clear button

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript, angular-material

I was looking for a cross-browser search control with clear button similar to HTML5

```html
<input type="search">
```

rendered by Chrome:
[image]

The most relevant results I am getting with [this code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xtsrs1?file=app/input-clearable-example.html) where I used the standard sample with "no appearance" as I don't need the underscore and some other styles applied:
[image]

```html
<mat-form-field class="example-form-field" appearance="none">
  <input matInput type="text" placeholder="Clearable input" [(ngModel)]="value">
  <button mat-button *ngIf="value" matSuffix mat-icon-button aria-label="Clear" (click)="value=''">
    <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
  </button>
</mat-form-field>
```

But the button might be floating up and down in different cases:

[image]

UPD. It is not a search for the library, book or tutorial :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Love the attention to detail here... I would put this one CSS in your **input-clearable-example.css**:

```
input.mat-input-element{margin-top:0; padding-bottom:7px;}
```

or ng-deep (in case it doesn't work... although it should)

```
::ng-deep input.mat-input-element{margin-top:0; padding-bottom:7px;}
```

Working [stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xtsrs1-reklhf)

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately both options do not work :( Do we need to update the styles of the input or of the button?

Comment: @BorisSokolov, I have updated the question with the result that I see... can you open the forked stackblitz link (in the answer) and let me know if t works for you?

Comment: Ah... it appears a bit differently in FireFox :(

Comment: In Chrome looks just fine

Comment: `input.mat-input-element{ margin-top: 0; padding-bottom: 15px;}` would work in firefox... it is almost 2020 and the browsers are still not "completely standard" :(